# I want to know clearly why and when we use seam injection and outjection?

Tags: jboss-seam

I want to know clearly why and when we use seam injection and outjection? I find and research all day but i can't clearly see it.Please help me.I will appreciate all of your supports.We can import bean and call it properties and methods.That's right?what's the difference? 
They means injection like that
@In
Specifies that a component attribute is to be injected from a context variable at the beginning of each component invocation. If the context variable is null, an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you understand [Depedency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) as a concept first. Then get a copy of [Seam in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/seam-in-action). Your chapter of choice is chapter 6.

I'm sorry the question really is far too general to give a conclusion about the concepts.

Comment: Thanks.Your answer is quite enough for me.